# Where is a Non-Syncing Windows 10 OneNote Notebook Saved?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onenote

I had a OneNote Notebook on the Windows 10 Store version of OneNote, which requires the file to be synced up to OneDrive. About 6 months ago, though, my Notebook stopped syncing up to the OneDrive servers, and I wasn't able to make it snyc again. My changes to the Notebook continued to be saved locally despite the broken sync feature, though.

Yesterday, I transitioned to a new PC and, as part of the transition, wiped my drive. The synced version on OneDrive is about 6 months old, and I'm obviously no longer able to access the local-cache of my Notebook. However, I have a full backup of my drive. I'd like to be able to get that local cache of the NoteBook back.

Does anyone know where a non-syncing OneNote Notebook being modified with the Windows 10 version of OneNote would be saved?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article.

[https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-move-your-synced-onedrive-files-to-a-new-location/#:~:text=relocate%2Donedrive%2Dfolder.&text=The%20OneDrive%20sync%20client%20is,folder%20in%20your%20user%20profile](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-move-your-synced-onedrive-files-to-a-new-location/#:%7E:text=relocate%2Donedrive%2Dfolder.&text=The%20OneDrive%20sync%20client%20is,folder%20in%20your%20user%20profile).

If you did nothing special, the local cache is stored in a top level folder of your user's main folder.

> By default, your files are stored in a top-level folder in your user
> profile. But if you have a second data drive (including a MicroSD
> card), you can choose that location instead, saving space on your
> system drive.
>
> The option to change the sync folder location appears when you first
> set up OneDrive. If you want to change the location after you've
> already completed setup, follow these steps: